# Use of undeclared identifier UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a Unity plugin (Open Setting in device).

```
extern "C"
{
    void _OpenSettings()
    {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error in XCode 5.1.1:

```
use of undeclared identifier UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
```

I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` was added in iOS 8 so you can't use it with iOS 7. There is no way to launch the app's portion of the Settings app in iOS 7.

Upgrade to Xcode 6 and iOS 8.